# .htaccess & web.py, preserving access to static folder after SetHandler fcgid-script

Tags: python, .htaccess, web.py

I have the following .htaccess in root in order to launch a web.py app:

```
allow from all
SetHandler fcgid-script
Options +ExecCGI
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.py/$1 [PT]
```

Everything works fine except the fact I can't access the static folder with css etc.

This is the code in the app.py:

```
import web
from getImgUrl import search

render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
  '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        term = search()
        return render.index(term[0], term[1])

web.wsgi.runwsgi = lambda func, addr=None: web.wsgi.runfcgi(func, addr)
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding an .htaccess file in the `static` folder:

```
SetHandler None
```